# How to get onInit() the current count of items in thumbnails Fancybox 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm trying to get current count of images in onInit() function Fancybox v3

```
onInit: function() {
 if(___Count_of_Thumbnails___ > 4){
       var left = $('html');
       var right= $('html');
       setTimeout(function() {
           // if($('.fancyfunc').length > 5){
               $(".fancybox-container")
                   .append(left)
                   .append(right);
           // }

       }, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instance.group` is array containing all gallery items, so you can get item count like this:

```
onInit: function(instance) {
  console.info(instance.group.length);
}
```

FYI, `instance.$refs` contains references to interface elements, for example, `instance.$refs.container` would be container element.